# "<Program> has stopped working" explanation

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2009

Can someone explain me when Windows shows this message?
What do i have to do to stop my Program from throwing this exception?

I have a Delphi Windows Forms Program which throws this message short after doing some SQL operations. 
So i do the SQL, everything seems fine at first, but at a random time after that windows is killing it by showing this message...

the intresting thing is, it only occours while debugging. 
When i'm not debugging it's running perfectly stable.
EDIT: Using RAD-Studio2009

I dont want to turn off the message completely(Only hint i found by using Google) 
i want to stop my program giving windows a Reason to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows shows this message when an unhandled exception leaks out of your application. This is a fatal condition. Something very wrong has happened with your application because exceptions should all be caught.

You need to work out what is throwing the exception and why it is not being caught. The very first step is to expand the details of the error dialog and find out which module the fault is occurring in, what the fault is and so on. That should yield some high level clues at the very least.

Most likely the Delphi debugger will not be able to help you for such a fault. You need to configure your system to arrange for a crash dump to be produced by the Windows Error Reporting service. Then you can load up the error report in a tool like WinDbg and try to figure it out.

Comment: Hm... 
I will search for an unhandeled exception
but this still does not explain why its only happing while running in a debugger....

Comment: @BigM Well, it would be hard for us to be able to explain that!

Comment: i handled every exception that could possibly occour, still no change...

any other ideas?

Comment: It will be an unhandled exception, or a fatal exception. Get the crash dump and debug it.

Comment: I finally found the Problem in a Function i use in my initialization part

I'm using Functions of my colleague which seem to stop my Program from answering Windows-Messages

i now call Application.Processmessages after using them and everythin is fine